# GET transient field with zero int value in java spring data

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

We're making get requests through a controller. The model contains transient fields that are set in the controller. Only int fields that are not null or >0 are being returned by the controller. How can I allow a transient field to return a 0 value, as this is meaningful. In this case the transient fields are 'sentenceStart' and 'sentenceEnd'.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{match_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Match getMatch(@PathVariable("match_id") long matchId) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info("REQUESTED RETRIEVAL OF MATCH WITH ID: " + matchId);
    Match match = matchRepository.findOneById(matchId);
                match.setActualText(matchRepository.getText(match.getId()));
  match.setSentenceStart(matchRepository.getSentenceStart(match.getId()));    
    match.setSentenceEnd(matchRepository.getSentenceEnd(match.getId()));
    match.setSentenceID(matchRepository.getSentenceId(match.getId()));
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info("DONE. TOOK " + (end - start) + " MILLISECONDS.");
    return match;
} //getMatch()
```

Repository:

```
public interface MatchRepository extends JpaRepository<Match, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Match> {

@Query(value = "SELECT match_in_sentence_start FROM vTextMatch where match_id = :m_id LIMIT 1",
        nativeQuery = true)
int getSentenceStart(@Param("m_id") long matchId);

@Query(value = "SELECT match_in_sentence_end  FROM vTextMatch where match_id = :m_id LIMIT 1",
        nativeQuery = true)
int getSentenceEnd(@Param("m_id") long matchId);

}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "match_term")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Match {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "match_id", nullable = false)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "document_id", nullable = false)
private Long documentId;
@Column(name = "document_start")
private Integer documentStart;
@Column(name = "document_end")
private Integer documentEnd;
@Column(name = "is_meta", nullable = false)
private Boolean isMeta;
@Column(name = "date_inserted", nullable = false)
private Timestamp dateInserted;

@Transient
private String actualText;
@Transient
private int sentenceStart;
@Transient
private int sentenceEnd;
@Transient
private int sentenceID;

/*
|-------------------|
| AUXILIARY METHODS |
|-------------------|
 */

/*
|-------------------|
|SETTERS ANG GETTERS|
|-------------------|
 */

public int getSentenceStart() {
    return sentenceStart;
}

public void setSentenceStart(int sentenceStart) {
    this.sentenceStart = sentenceStart;
}

public int getSentenceEnd() {
    return sentenceEnd;
}

public void setSentenceEnd(int sentenceEnd) {
    this.sentenceEnd = sentenceEnd;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should investigate line containing @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) -  http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY

I would suggest slightly change your design and introduce some message type. You could avoid polluting your domain class with the not needed stuff.

Comment: Ah yes. There it is. I've changed this to 'NON_NULL' now which has done the trick.